# VS Code does not detect installed git

Tags: gitlab, visual-studio-code

My VS Code does not recognize installed git even after with seemingly correct settings.

I installed git through https://git-scm.com/ (64-bit windows) and that is available under C:\Program Files\git. The gitlab executable is under C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe. I am able to run git.exe from my command line and get the version information.

C:\Program Files\Git\bin>git --version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1

In my VS Code, I have the following in settings.json

```
{
    "git.enabled": true,
    "git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe",
    "scm.alwaysShowProviders": true
}
```

But I still see No source control providers registered under SOURCE CONTROL.

Answer (score 0):

This was my case :Mac OS Ventura M1 chip.

1. I installed via binary installer from git website
2. Run git --version : Prompt to Install developer tools
3. "which git" command in terminal gave installation path
4. It was installed on two locations : user/local/bin/git & user/bin/git
5. Due to which git : path inside VS code wasnt able to pick the installed git
6. Deleted the one installed in user/local/bin/git & set git:path as user/bin/git

Answer (score -1):

For better integration in Visual Studio Code I recommend to use a [Visual Studio Code Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). I already answered in another topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527976/4772880

Edit 1: According to [@fabian-lauer](/users/3861083/fabian-lauer) it seems unclear. I am personally using the GitLens Extension and everything works automatically.
I think the git integration in VS code itself only kicks in when you start `code` with a folder or file in a local repository, e.g. `code C:\GitRepo\`

Comment: The SO answer you link to is regarding a UI for git, but the question is about git itself not being found by VS Code.